# How do I create and manipulate a large number of JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing

I have written a sudoku solver in Java and want to make it visual. The following code creates a JTextField that will be used to input one of the numbers given in the sudoku puzzle:

```
public class Visual extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public Visual() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JTextField box00 = new JTextField("0", 3);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(box00);
    }
}
```

However, I need to add 81 JTextField boxes that will all have grid positions and need to be added to the panel. Is there a fast way to do this without writing out the code 81 times? I'm new to Java, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a `List` or array to maintain the fields, use loops to manage them

Comment: As @MadProgrammer said, you need to use a data structure.  A 2d array of type JTextField would be best, so you could add all your JTextFields into the array and manipulate it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Visual {

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

JTextField[][] box = new JTextField[9][9];

public Visual() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            box[i][j] = new JTextField("0", 3);
            gbc.gridx = i;
            gbc.gridy = j;
            panel.add(box[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, I didn't know you could put text fields in an array, I will be sure to use this a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2D array of `JTextField`s.

```
JTextField[][] box = new JTextField[9][9];
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        box[i][j] = new JTextField(...);
        panel.add(box[i][j]);
    }
}
```